WhatsApp not executing the AmpScript function
We are using a Cloudpage to track whether the WhatsApp CTA links are clicked. For this, a Cloudpage is embedded in the Meta template as the base URL for the CTA, with UTM parameters dynamically added from the SFMC Data Extension. The UTM parameters are formatted and passed into the CTA's dynamic variable using the TreatAsContent function. This setup was working fine a few days ago but has suddenly stopped. Below is the syntax we’ve been using for the CTA button:
%%=TreatAsContent(link_variable)=%%

The link_variable in the Data Extension contains the following value:
?sub=%%mobile%%&campaign_name=%%campaign_name%%&campaign_link=%%campaign_link%%

Once the Cloudpage receives these values, it stores them in the log Data Extension and redirects to the campaign_link.
We’ve tried the following combinations when attempting to populate the dynamic UTM post this issue occurred:
%%=TreatAsContent(AttributeValue('link_variable'))=%%

%%=TreatAsContent(sub=%%mobile%%&campaign_name=%%campaign_name%%&campaign_link=%%campaign_link%%)=%%
(This throws an error during the subscriber preview.)

%%link_variable%%

%%[%%=TreatAsContent(sub=%%mobile%%&campaign_name=%%campaign_name%%&campaign_link=%%campaign_link%%)=%%]%%


Also, when we use other attributes like %%Campaign_link%% or %%Campaign_name%%, they are being passed correctly.
